# Providers can't resolve an other provider in constructor's parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-providers

I'm developing a ionic v3 app : 
I declared all my providers but one of them can't be resolve in two others providers

I got this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DialogueMetier:([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object],?, [object Object], [object Object]).
```

this is my "not resolved" provider :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { TechniqueMetier } from './technique';
import { GlobalVarsMetier } from './global-vars';
import { SynchronisationMappingMetier } from './synchronisation-mapping-metier';
import { InformationBdd } from '../bdd/information-bdd';
import { OutilMetier } from './outil-metier';
import { NotificationMetier } from './notification-metier';
import { InformationActionMetier } from './information-action-metier';
import { InformationAssocieeMetier } from './information-associee-metier';
import { InformationDestinataireMetier } from './information-destinataire-metier';
import { InformationDossierMetier } from './information-dossier-metier';
import { EvenementMetier } from './evenement-metier';
import { DialogueMetier } from './dialogue-metier';
import { TacheMetier } from './tache-metier';
import { DocumentMetier } from './document-metier';

@Injectable()
export class InformationMetier {

constructor(
    public techniqueMetier : TechniqueMetier,
    public rootScope : GlobalVarsMetier,
    public synchronisationMappingMetier : SynchronisationMappingMetier,
    public informationBdd : InformationBdd,
    public outilMetier : OutilMetier,
    public notificationMetier : NotificationMetier,
    public informationActionMetier : InformationActionMetier,
    public informationAssocieeMetier : InformationAssocieeMetier,
    public informationDestinataireMetier : InformationDestinataireMetier,
    public informationDossierMetier : InformationDossierMetier,
    public evenementMetier : EvenementMetier,
    public dialogueMetier : DialogueMetier,
    public tacheMetier : TacheMetier,
    public documentMetier : DocumentMetier 
    ) {
}
```

and this is one that cannot resolve it :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InformationMetier } from './information-metier';
import { InformationAssocieeMetier } from './information-associee-metier';
import { InformationDestinataireMetier } from './information-destinataire-metier';
import { SynchronisationMappingMetier } from './synchronisation-mapping-metier';
import { DossierMetier } from './dossier-metier';
import { DialogueMessageMetier } from './dialogue-message-metier';
import { DialogueBdd } from '../bdd/dialogue-bdd';


@Injectable()
export class DialogueMetier {

    constructor(
        public synchronisationMappingMetier : SynchronisationMappingMetier,
        public informationAssocieeMetier : InformationAssocieeMetier,
        public informationDestinataireMetier : InformationDestinataireMetier,
        public dossierMetier : DossierMetier,
        public informationMetier : InformationMetier,
        public dialogueMessageMetier : DialogueMessageMetier,
        public dialogueBdd : DialogueBdd) {
    }
```

I try to understand what's wrong.
I put all of providers in provider's declaration in app.module.ts.

Is someone know what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of circular dependency In your case,  InformationMetier depends on DialogueMetier which depends InformationMetier.

> When Angular’s bootstrap process tries to setup all the services and
>   inject each service’s dependencies, it detects when such a scenario
>   happens and errors out, instead of getting stuck in an infinite loop.

You need to refactor any one of your service so that it does not require a reference to another service.